# Obtaining Wifi connectivity notification while in background

Tags: ios, iphone

Is it possible to get notifications about Wifi connectivity state while an iOS app is running in the background? It is looking like a no, but I am also curious if this could be checked during a background fetch routine.

Comment: Hi, I think u can do during background fetch using reachability.

Comment: Why do you need to be notified about WiFi connectivity? Do you need to upload, download or distribute something while app in background?

Comment: @Sachin I am using Reachability. The problem is I want to know if the wifi disconnects/connects while the app is in the background. I did some tests with background fetch and it is too unpredictable to even get close results.

Comment: @Keenle I am trying to create a log of when I am connected/disconnected from my wifi for a personal app.

Comment: @DurianShredder Yes u r right background fetch is unpredictable. But that is only your hope. In Background rechabillty wont work

Answer (score 0):

You have limited options to get processor time while in background and as far as I know there is no direct option to be notified on the WiFi status. Here you can find the modes of background execution: [apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW20)

I have tried with VOIP support to keep a stream opened while the app was in background. Everything worked ok and I was getting connectivity errors when the connection was lost, also I was able to try to reconnect from time to time until the connection was back on.
The only problem is that Apple will not approve the app unless your app provides a VOIP functionality (although the first two versions of the app were approved and only on the third one it got rejected because of flagging VOIP but not actually providing it).

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I was wondering if apple would flag me if I tried something like that.

Comment: Well ... sometimes it's pure luck and you might pass under Apple's radar. But there's also one more downside of this: the battery consumption (it was dropping a lot even at a 10 minutes ping).